# ExtJS4: Find DOM element of tree node

Tags: dom, extjs, extjs4, treenode

I want to run automated UI tests in my ExtJS4 application. I don't want to use Siesta, the Testing Tool from Sencha. Instead, I want to use a custom tool.

The application uses a TreePanel. To support the automated UI test, it is mandatory that each treenode (Ext.data.NodeInterface) has a unique and language independent identifier as attribute in its HTML representation.

This identifier should be set at the treenode when added to the tree. A custom ExtJS plugin for the treepanel should then render the identifier from the treenode object to its HTML representation.

So, my problem is: How do I get the DOM element of an Ext.data.NodeInterface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had some pending questions. A accepted them now. :)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to explicitly define the DOM id of each tree node? That is, the programmer (you, I guess) will have a config per node that will end up as the DOM element id?

Comment: No, I want to extend the DOM element of node with a custom attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the record ID of the node you are trying to target then you can try the following:

```
var myNode = tree.getStore().getNodeById(id);
var nodeElement = tree.getView().getNode(myNode);
```